# pointer being freed was not allocated (osx only)

Tags: c, pointers, free, dirname

The function below basically emulates `mkdir -p`, recursively creating directories for a given path. With Linux I have no issues, however running under OSX it always segfaults with the error `pointer being freed was not allocated` during the call to `free(dir)`. Can anyone spot an error? When I step through execution in gdb I don't see any obvious problems, `dir` is populated and the directory structure is created without error.

```
static int
mkpath(const char *path)
{
  int result = 0;
  struct stat st;
  char *p = NULL, *dir = strdup(path);
  char *tmp = g_malloc0(sizeof(char) * strlen(cache.path) + strlen(dir) + 1);

  dir = dirname(dir);
  tmp = strcpy(tmp, cache.path);
  p = strtok(dir, "/");
  while(p != NULL) {
    tmp = strncat(tmp, "/", 1);
    tmp = strncat(tmp, p, strlen(p));

    if(stat(tmp, &st) == 0) {
      if(S_ISDIR(st.st_mode)) {
        p = strtok(NULL, "/");
        continue;
      }

      result = -ENOTDIR;
      break;
    }

    if(mkdir(tmp, S_IRWXU) == -1) {
      result = -errno;
      break;
    }

    p = strtok(NULL, "/");
  }

  free(tmp);
  free(dir);

  return result;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at the man page for dirname: http://linux.die.net/man/3/dirname.  "Both dirname() and basename() return pointers to null-terminated strings. (Do not pass these pointers to free(3).)"  Also, you should probably not being doing dir = dirname(dir) as you've then lost the pointer to the memory allocated by strdup (strdup allocated memory *should* be passed to free).

Answer (score 1):

The [man page for `dirname`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/dirname) says that you should not pass the return value to `free()`.  Yet that is exactly what you are doing.

Answer (score 1):

according to the man page:

> WARNINGS
>        The dirname() function returns a pointer to internal static storage space that will be overwritten by
>        subsequent calls (each function has its own separate storage).

so you probably don't want to be freeing it. i'm guessing that's different on linux?